# UIToolbar goes under status bar in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, interface-builder, uitoolbar, uistatusbar

I have a UIView and I have a UIToolbar and UIWebView.
I want to show toolbar at top of UIView and after that the rest of page covered with webView.
But toolbar goes under status bar like this
[image]

How can I correct it in iOS7.

Comment: are you using xib or prog?

Answer (score 13):

1) Set the toolbar Y position to 20 (in the interface builder or in the code)

2) Set the toolbar delegate

3) In your toolbar delegate implement:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Set up toolbar delegate to your view controller and implement method:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you still have to move your toolbar 20pt below.

Comment: You saved my day! Don't forget to set toolbar.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

The only correct solution in 2k17 is to attach your toolbar/navigationBar to `leading/trailing` of your `superview`, `top` to `topLayoutGuideBottom` and to implement `positionForBar:`. This will produce correct result on all devices.